# powershell csv loop PSCustomObject

Tags: powershell, csv

[image: Sample Input and Output]

I am trying to iterate the VM names and storing them in PSCustomObject and assign a subnet in order wise in output like the following:
VM1 Subnet1
VM2 Subnet2
VM3 Subnet3
VM4 Subnet1
VM5 Subnet2
How to achieve this.

```
$csv = import-csv C:\ps\sample.csv
$myobject = foreach ($line in $csv){
    if ($line.count -gt 0) {
        for($i = 0; $i -lt $line.count; $i++){
            $count = $i + 1
                [pscustomobject]@{
                VMName = $line.vmname+$count
                Subnet = $line.subnet -split ',' | Get-Random
                Sku    = $line.sku
                os     = $line.os
                }
            }
        }
    }
$myobject
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this code does the job:

```
$csv = import-csv C:\ps\sample.csv -Delimiter ';'
$myobject = foreach ($line in $csv){
    if ($line.count -gt 0) {
        for($i = 0; $i -lt $line.count; $i++){
            $ar_sub = $line.subnet -split ','
            $l_sub = $ar_sub.count

                [pscustomobject]@{
                VMName = $line.vmname+$count
                Subnet = $ar_sub[$i % $l_sub]
                Sku    = $line.sku
                os     = $line.os
                }
            }
        }
    }
$myobject
```

result:

```
VMName Subnet  Sku      os    
------ ------  ---      --    
appvm1 subnet1 t2.mciro centos
appvm2 subnet2 t2.mciro centos
appvm3 subnet3 t2.mciro centos
appvm4 subnet1 t2.mciro centos
appvm5 subnet2 t2.mciro centos
dbvm1  subnet4 t3.micro centos
dbvm2  subnet5 t3.micro centos
dbvm3  subnet6 t3.micro centos
dbvm4  subnet4 t3.micro centos
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! Frenchy. Could you please explain this part Subnet = $ar_sub[$i % $l_sub] alone. In loop, how it adds the next value. I was browsing through lots of forums to find an answer, but no luck. Thanks Again!!! :)

Comment: % is the function modulo. It's purely math